# Open another one of my apps with a UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I have 2 apps that I have made and I would like to be able to open one of them from the other. Is there any way to do this? And if possible, I would like to be able to transfer information from one to the other that doesn't involve the Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement a URL scheme. For example, if one app's URL scheme is `appone://`, then you can launch app one from app two like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"appone://"]];
```

You can learn how to implement a URL scheme [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Comment: Is there any way to transfer objects to my other app as well? (without internet)

Comment: Don't think that's possible without internet.

Answer (score 2):

You register a custom URL (like MyApp://some_information) and then open that URL from your other application. See this: [Communicating with Other Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html).